# Nested Attributes for a Rich Join Table, using simple_form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, simple-form, nested-forms

I want to create a form that has nested attributes, which populates a record within a rich join table. (That created record within the rich join table of course should have the appropriate foreign keys.)

I have yet to find a thorough answer on creating nested form fields on a `has_many :through` relationship.  Please help!

For this example, I have a user form. Within that form, I am also trying to populate a record within the `users_pets` table (rich join table).

Additional question: are rich join models supposed to be singular or plural?  Example: `app/models/owners_pets.rb` or `app/models/owners_pet.rb`.

***app/models/owner.rb***

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners_pets, allow_destroy: true
    has_many :pets, through: :owners_pets
end
```

***app/models/pet.rb***

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners_pets, allow_destroy: true
    has_many :owners, through: :owners_pets
end
```

***app/models/owners_pets.rb***

```
class OwnersPet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owners
    belongs_to :pets
end
```

***app/controller/owners.rb***

```
def owner_params
    params.require(:owner).permit(:first_name, owners_pets_attributes: [:id, :pet_name, :pet_id])
end
```

***app/views/owners/_form.html.erb***

```
<%= simple_form_for(@owner) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :owners_pets do |ff|
        <%= ff.input :pet_name %>
    <% end %>
    <div>
       <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer, thanks to a bunch of help from a mentor.  It helps me to keep in mind that rich join naming conventions should NOT be pluralized at the very end, just like other non-rich-join models.  Ex: `book_page.rb` NOT `books_pages.rb.`  Even `books_page.rb` would work (just update your strong params and database table accordingly). The important part is that the entire model must follow the rails convention of the model being singular (no 's' on the end).

Below in the rich join model, I made the decision to name it the *completely singular version*: `owner_pet.rb` as opposed to the other version: `owners_pet.rb`. (Therefore of course, my database table is named: `owner_pets`)

***app/models/owner.rb***

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owner_pets
    has_many :pets, through: :owner_pets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner_pets, allow_destroy: true
end
```

***app/models/pet.rb***

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owner_pets
    has_many :owners, through: :owner_pets
end
```

***app/models/owner_pet.rb***

```
class OwnerPet < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner
    belongs_to :pet
end
```

***app/controller/owners.rb***

```
def new
    @owner = Owner.new
    @owner.owner_pets.build
end
private
  def owner_params
      params.require(:owner).permit(:first_name, owner_pets_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :pet_name, :pet_id, :owner_id])
  end
```

***app/views/owners/_form.html.erb***

```
<%= simple_form_for(@owner) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :owner_pets do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.input :pet_name %>
        <%= ff.input :pet_id, collection: Pet.all, label_method: "pet_type" %>
    <% end %>
    <div>
       <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join table is the problem:

It should be `belongs_to :owners belongs_to :pets` for the join table to work

Plus the rich join model should be pluralised, as in: `owners_pets`

Comment: thank you for answering my question about the rich join model naming convention, and thank you for catching the rich join association errors.  I did update the code.  unfortuantely it is still not working and I am unsure why.